# php read start from zero number case

Tags: php, numbers, zero

May you can help me...
many years ago my friend gave me php script code presented below, now i want to change it can read numbering start from zero

existing just possible read 1:1, 10:200 etc.. but i want to make also possible read from 01:01, 0000002:0120 etc...

```
function is_valid_number($sesuatu)
 {
 if(preg_match("/^([0-9]+)$/", $sesuatu)) return(TRUE);
 else return(FALSE);
 }


//--------------

if(isset($teks["chapter"]) && (is_valid_number($teks["chapter"]) === FALSE))
 {
 if(strcmp($teks["chapter"], "") != 0) echo "".Chapter_need_number.""; //bhs
 unset($teks["chapter"]); //Just get rid of it.
 }
if(isset($teks["verse"]) && (is_valid_number($teks["verse"]) === FALSE))
 {
 //There is a non-numerical character in verse. We /should/ be able to examine it for range.
 $temp_array = explode("-", $teks["verse"], 2);
 if(isset($temp_array[0]) && isset($temp_array[1]) && is_valid_number($temp_array[0]) === TRUE && is_valid_number($temp_array[1]) === TRUE)
  {
  $teks["verse"] = $temp_array[0];
  $teks["verse_end"] = $temp_array[1];
 // echo ("<h3>".Verse_range." \"" . $temp_array[0] . "\" - \"" . $temp_array[1] . "\"</h3>\n"); //bhs
  if($teks["verse_end"] <= $teks["verse"])
   {
   echo "".Verse_range_need_larger_ending."";//bhs
   unset($teks["verse"]);
   unset($teks["verse_end"]);
   }
  }
 else
  {
  if(strcmp($teks["verse"], "") != 0) echo "".Verse_need_number.""; //bhs
  unset($teks["verse"]); //Just get rid of it.
  }
 }
if(isset($teks["verse"]) && !isset($teks["chapter"]))
 {
 echo "".Verse_need_chapter.""; //bhs
 unset($teks["verse"]); //Just get rid of it.
 }

//--------------
```

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make use of php internal functions like `is_numeric` and `empty`. And refrain from using string concatenation with empty strings (for whatever reason), instead just make sure those constants (I guess they are constants) are compatible and everything is fine.

```
if ( isset( $teks['chapter'] ) && !is_numeric( $teks['chapter' ) )
{
    if ( !empty( $teks['chapter'] ) )
        echo Chapter_need_number;
    unset( $teks['chapter'] );
}

if ( isset( $teks['verse'] ) && !is_numeric( $teks['verse'] ) )
{
    $temp_array = explode( '_', teks['verse'], 2 );
    if ( count( $temp_array ) >= 2 && is_numeric( $temp_array[0] ) && is_numeric( $temp_array[1] ) )
    {
        $teks['verse'] = intval( $temp_array[0] );
        $teks['verse_end'] = intval( $temp_array[1] );
        if ( teks['verse_end'] <= teks['verse'] )
        {
            echo Verse_range_need_larger_ending;
            unset( $teks['verse'] );
            unset( $teks['verse_end'] );
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if ( !empty( $teks['verse'] ) )
            echo Verse_need_number;
        unset( $teks['verse'] );
    }
}
if ( isset( $teks['verse'] ) && !isset( $teks['chapter'] ) )
{
    echo Verse_need_chapter;
    unset( $teks['verse'] );
}
```

Comment: Thank You for your nice input... i will do your suggestions for this topic... if you wish i have another link that maybe you inform there http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960441/make-output-parallel-with-php-code-based/1963426#1963426

Comment: Hi Poke, Everything you typed i did, but change nothing bro.

Comment: Hi Poke...
how if i send you the complete script? because i am new to php, and just looking for some help, if you agree would you if i send the script through by email. Regards

Comment: Just upload it to pastebin.com and add the link in your question

Comment: Sorry that I didn't answer, however I suggest you to open a new question about that as I'm currently quite busy and can't look through the code that quickly. By opening a new question you invite others to help you as well.

Comment: Oh... no Problem, just do your activity 1st and hopefully all be  right, thx

Answer (score 0):

I'm gonna take a wild guess here, becuase I didn't quite get the question, but I think you should change this:

```
if($teks["verse_end"] <= $teks["verse"])
```

to this

```
if(intval($teks["verse_end"]) <= intval($teks["verse"]))
```

Comment: Thank You for your nice input... i will do your suggestions for this topic... if you wish i have another link that maybe you inform there http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960441/make-output-parallel-with-php-code-based/1963426#1963426

Comment: Hi Oscar, also you typed i did all but nothing happens, tq